# How to eager load associations properly in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eager-loading

I have two models: a `Person` has many `Blurb(s)`.

In the controller I'm fetching all people and eagerly loading blurbs:

```
@people = Person.includes(:blurbs).all.sort { |x, y| y.updated_at <=> x.updated_at }
```

Then in the view I iterate through `@people` and display their individual blurb counts:

```
<% @people.each do |person| %>
  <%= person.blurbs.count %>
<% end %>
```

Rails' logger shows that all blurbs are indeed loaded:

```
Blurb Load (0.5ms) SELECT "blurbs".* FROM "blurbs" WHERE "blurbs"."person_id" IN \
(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, \
21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 27, 48, 49, 50)
```

But then it loads them all again when iterating instead of fetching from cache:

```
(0.4ms) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "blurbs" WHERE "blurbs"."person_id" = $1  [["person_id", 27]]
(0.3ms) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "blurbs" WHERE "blurbs"."person_id" = $1  [["person_id", 50]]
(0.3ms) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "blurbs" WHERE "blurbs"."person_id" = $1  [["person_id", 49]]
```

What am I missing to use the eagerly loaded blurbs in order to cut down on the SQL queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eager loading, as you have implemented above, will not cache counts.  What you may be looking for to prevent those multiple “SELECT COUNT…” queries is a counter_cache.

You can implement it as follows:

```
class Blurb < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person, counter_cache: true
end
```

…and then add a column to your Person table called `blurbs_count`

You can also specify a custom column if you so desire:

```
belongs_to :person, counter_cache: :count_of_blurbs
```

See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html for more info.

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider a `counter_cache` a bit OTT for this case. Try `person.blurbs.size` instead.

In short, `size` will conditionally call either `length` or `count` depending on previous queries.

#### From ActiveRecord source:

```
# File activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb, line 228
def size
  loaded? ? @records.length : count
end
```